# Dynamic partial in handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

The below code working fine but routes `/` and `/signup` will show same thing (except title) because the first argument in the res.render doesn't do anything and because in the layout I have `{{< index}}` which render the view with the name index. What I want is to dynamically pass the partial that I want to render (basically I want the first argument of res.render to have effect).

app.js

```
/* Variable declarations */
var express =   require('express'),
    hbs     =   require('hbs'),
    app     =   express();

/* Setttings */
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('view options', { layout: 'layout' });

/* Register Partials */
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views');

/* Routes */
app.get('/signup', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {title: 'Welcome'});
});
app.get('/signup', function (req, res) {
    res.render('signup', {title: 'Sign Up'});
});

/* Listeners */
app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('App started...');
});
```

Layout.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{title}}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{> index}}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As part of Handlerbars 3.0 dynamic partials are included. You can find the reference [here](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html). With this new syntax the name of the partial is evaluated and dynamically replaced. I'm using `"express-handlebars": "2.0.1",`.

Layout.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{> (whichPartial) }}
  </body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
/* Routes */
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.render('index', {title: 'Welcome'
        whichPartial: function() {
             return "thePartialNameForIndex";
        }
   });
});
app.get('/signup', function (req, res) {
   res.render('signup', {title: 'Sign Up'
       whichPartial: function() {
             return "thePartialNameForSignup";
       }
   });
});
```

Where `thePartialNameForIndex` and `thePartialNameForSignup` are the name of the partials allocated in `/views`.